# About ||||| (pipe or vertical bars) In yad --form --button

Tags: yad

During Working with yad --form displayed some |||(vertical bars) after clicked a button, what are this bars indicating & how I can STOP them to display?
Providing sample code, You can experience

```
yad --width=400 --height=200 --button="gtk-ok" --form --field="Click Down":LBL "echo Clicked" --field="Click HERE":BTN
```

Result output will be "
**Clicked** *then* 
**||**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the situation you describe entirely, but I think you need to ask yourself what you want `yad` to do when a button is pressed, or, more specifically, how `yad` should communicate any user choice back to you, i.e. via an exit code *or* via information on standard output.

The option `--button="gtk-ok"` creates a button that is not tied to an exit code with which `yad` can exit and silently let you know that this particular button was pressed. Consequently, it seems, it will try to inform you via output on stdout (printing two default output separator characters). To prevent this, you could rephrase the option, e.g. like so:

```
--button="gtk-ok":1
```

which ties an exit code of `1` to pressing the OK button, and prevents further output. At the command prompt (or in a script), you can test this exit code, which is available as `$?`.

Importantly: note that the `yad` manpage indicates that the proper syntax for the `--button'-option is:

> --button=BUTTON:ID
>   Add  the dialog button. May be used multiply times. ID is an exit code or a command. (...)

So the option `--button="gtk-ok" seems to be syntactically incorrect.

---

To get the behaviour your describe, I had to change `--field="Click Down":LBL "echo Clicked"` into `--field="Click Down":BTN "echo Clicked"`.

---

All in all, the following command works as expected on my system:

```
yad --width=400 --height=200 --button="gtk-ok":1 --form --field="Click Down":BTN "echo Clicked" --field="Click HERE":BTN
```

Comment: ozzy, as you said by set gtk-ok":1 ,I skipped ||||||(vertical bars), but when I set gtk-ok:2 again I got vertical bars, In my bash script yad comes 3 times continuously and interesting point is whenever **gtk-ok:EVEN NUMBER** then I got vertical bars. Is there any special relation with even number ?

Comment: I Just skipped All vertical bars by setting ODD NUMBERS, So Why EVEN?

Comment: @AlpaCoder In the yad manpage, under EXIT CODES, it says “Even exit code mean to print result, odd just return result”. So this behaviour is apparently by design.